# Python: Import standard module in two different files in the same package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Say I have a package with two files

```
my_package/
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
```

`file2.py` includes the following

```
from collections import defaultdict

class classA(object):
```

Now I want to use the `defaultdict` module in both `file1.py` and `file2.py`. I am confused between these two methods

**Method 1**

`file1.py` includes the following

```
from collections import defaultdict

from file1 import classA
```

**Method 2**

`file1.py` includes the following

```
from file1 import *
```

My question is which is the better (i.e. more pythonic) way to do this and why? Or is there an entirely different way of doing it as well that I'm missing. Also, would the solution vary if importing non-standard python libraries?

Comment: Just put `from collections import defaultdic` (or should it be `defaultdict`?) To both your files. And never use `import *`

Comment: Yes, it should be `defaultdict`.